# How to refactor Symfony 5 controller to comply with SOLID design principles

Tags: symfony, dependencies, solid-principles

I am trying to create this API endpoint that will accept JSON payload and will calculate quote based on provided factors and their ratings.

I have Entities that contain ratings about

- "age"
- "postcode"
- "ABI code"

These AgeRating, PostcodeRating and AbiRating entities implement RatingFactorInterface to force implementation of `getRatingFactor()` method.

QuoteController seems to be violating "Single Responsibility" and "Open/Close" design principles as the factors like "age", "postcode" can change - extra factor can be added or one of the factors might not be used.

I was thinking maybe it would be possible for rating factors to be specified in the dependency injection container, but can't seem to find a good example how this would work especially with factors that depend on other services like AbiCodeRating which also depends on ABI code which is returned by using third party API which accepts car registration number.

**How do I refactor the controller and services so I'm not violating Single Responsibility and Open / Close design principles?**

### POST JSON Payload example

```
{
    "age": 20,
    "postcode": "PE3 8AF",
    "regNo": "PJ63 LXR"
}
```

### QuoteController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\AbiCodeRatingRepository;
use App\Repository\AgeRatingRepository;
use App\Repository\PostcodeRatingRepository;
use App\Service\AbiCodeLookup;
use App\Service\QuoteCalculator;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class QuoteController
 * @package App\Controller
 */
class QuoteController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="quote")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AbiCodeRatingRepository $abiCodeRatingRepository
     * @param AgeRatingRepository $ageRatingRepository
     * @param PostcodeRatingRepository $postcodeRatingRepository
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function index(Request $request, AbiCodeRatingRepository $abiCodeRatingRepository, AgeRatingRepository $ageRatingRepository, PostcodeRatingRepository $postcodeRatingRepository)
    {
        try{

            $request = $this->transformJsonBody($request);

            /**
             * Quoting engine could be used with a different set of rating factors!
             * Meaning age, postcode and regNo maybe not be required, some other rating factors might be introduced
             * How to make controller to accept rating factors dynamically?
             */
            if (!$request || !$request->get('age') || !$request->request->get('postcode') || !$request->get('regNo')){
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            /**
             * call to a third party API to look up the vehicle registration number and return an ABI code
             * this is only required if AbiRating is used with the quoting engine
             */
            $abiCode          = AbiCodeLookup::getAbiCode($request->get('regNo'));
            /**
             * $abiCode is only required if postcodeRating is used by quoting engine
             */
            $ratingFactors[]  = $abiCodeRatingRepository->findOneBy(["abiCode"=>$abiCode]);
            $ratingFactors[]  = $ageRatingRepository->findOneBy(["age"=>$request->get("age")]);
            /**
             * $area is only required if postcodeRating is used by quoting engine
             */
            $area             = substr($request->get("postcode"),0,3);
            $ratingFactors[]  = $postcodeRatingRepository->findByPostcodeArea($area);
            $premiumTotal     = QuoteCalculator::calculate($ratingFactors);

            $data = [
                'status' => 200,
                'success' => "Quote created successfully",
                'quote' => $premiumTotal
            ];

            return new JsonResponse($data,200);

        }catch (\Exception $e){
            $data = [
                'status' => 422,
                'errors' => "Data is not valid",
            ];
            return new JsonResponse($data,422);
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Request
     */
    protected function transformJsonBody(Request $request)
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        if ($data === null) {
            return $request;
        }

        $request->request->replace($data);

        return $request;
    }
}
```

### AbiCodeRating

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\AbiCodeRatingRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"get","post"},
 *     itemOperations={"get"}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AbiCodeRatingRepository::class)
 */
class AbiCodeRating implements RatingFactorInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $abiCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ratingFactor;


    public function getAbiCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->abiCode;
    }

    public function setAbiCode(string $abiCode): self
    {
        $this->abiCode = $abiCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRatingFactor(): ?float
    {
        return $this->ratingFactor;
    }

    public function setRatingFactor(?float $ratingFactor): self
    {
        $this->ratingFactor = $ratingFactor;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

### AgeRating

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\AgeRatingRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"get","post"},
 *     itemOperations={"get"}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AgeRatingRepository::class)
 */
class AgeRating implements RatingFactorInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $age;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ratingFactor;


    public function getAge(): ?int
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    public function setAge(int $age): self
    {
        $this->age = $age;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRatingFactor(): ?float
    {
        return $this->ratingFactor;
    }

    public function setRatingFactor(?float $ratingFactor): self
    {
        $this->ratingFactor = $ratingFactor;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

### PostcodeRating

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PostcodeRatingRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PostcodeRatingRepository::class)
 */
class PostcodeRating implements RatingFactorInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4)
     */
    private $postcodeArea;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ratingFactor;

    public function getPostcodeArea(): ?string
    {
        return $this->postcodeArea;
    }

    public function setPostcodeArea(string $postcodeArea): self
    {
        $this->postcodeArea = $postcodeArea;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRatingFactor(): ?float
    {
        return $this->ratingFactor;
    }

    public function setRatingFactor(?float $ratingFactor): self
    {
        $this->ratingFactor = $ratingFactor;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

### RatingFactorInterface

```
<?php


namespace App\Entity;


interface RatingFactorInterface
{
    /**
     * @return float|null
     */
    public function getRatingFactor(): ?float;
}
```

### AbiCodeRatingRepository

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\AbiCodeRating;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method AbiCodeRating|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method AbiCodeRating|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method AbiCodeRating[]    findAll()
 * @method AbiCodeRating[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class AbiCodeRatingRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, AbiCodeRating::class);
    }

   
}
```

### AgeRatingRepository

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\AgeRating;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method AgeRating|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method AgeRating|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method AgeRating[]    findAll()
 * @method AgeRating[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class AgeRatingRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, AgeRating::class);
    }
}
```

### PostcodeRatingRepository

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\PostcodeRating;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method PostcodeRating|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method PostcodeRating|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method PostcodeRating[]    findAll()
 * @method PostcodeRating[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class PostcodeRatingRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, PostcodeRating::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return PostcodeRating Returns PostcodeRating objects based on area
     */

    public function findByPostcodeArea($area): ?PostcodeRating
    {
        return $this->findOneBy(["postcodeArea"=>$area]);
    }
}
```

### AbiCodeLookup

```
<?php
namespace App\Service;

class AbiCodeLookup
{
    public static function getAbiCode(string $regNumber){

        /**
         * create a request to third party api which would return abi code
         * How to configure this service to be used only with regNo factor
         */
        return "22529902";
    }
}
```

### QuoteCalculator

```
<?php
    namespace App\Service;
    use App\Entity\RatingFactorInterface;
    
    /**
     * Class QuoteCalculator
     */
    class QuoteCalculator
    {
        /**
         * @param array $ratingFactors
         * @return float
         */
        public static function calculate(array $ratingFactors): float
        {
            $premiumTotal = 500;
            foreach ($ratingFactors as $ratingFactor){
                $premiumTotal = $premiumTotal * ($ratingFactor instanceof RatingFactorInterface ? $ratingFactor->getRatingFactor() : 1);
            }
            return $premiumTotal ;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Is this code working? This may be better suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: what makes you think you're violating the SOLID principles? because I can't really see any violation for single responsibility or open/close ...

Comment: @Jakumi In my humble opinion a controller should online care about handling the request then hand the input over to the service or services than handle the logic. In the OP's code, the controller coordinates the logic (it knows which repositories to call, which criteria to apply, which services to execute...). I don't like the static calls either, most of the time they just hide dependencies and violate DI... being just structured code in a class oriented disguise. All said... I'm not sure StackOverflow is the place to post this since questions should be specific and answers non opinnionated..

Comment: @Astaroth - I agree that controller should handle request, but what exactly would this mean for the rest of the code? should I create multiple services that will be added to controller as a dependency injection and create service configuration so that service is autoloaded? what about transformJsonBody method, is this supposed to be an EventSubscriber which executes as middleware between client and controller? can you provided some example on how you would separate the concerns and how would you configure DI?

Comment: @anonymous007 I'll continue in the question on codereview https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250896/how-to-refactor-symfony-5-controller-to-comply-with-solid-design-principles

Comment: @Astaroth fair enough. In theory I absolutely agree, as you noted it's all about tradeoffs. I would probably move it to another service as soon as a second client is added that needs the same logic. also, nice code review.

Comment: @Astaroth, i'm replying here as i have no privilege to comment on codereview... You are right RatingFactors come from the Request, also i have created an EventSubscriber that is converting json payload into array just before it reaches controller - this is probably what you call the Transformer class, ParamConverter is going to help here, thanks for that. Is it actually possible to use a ParamConverter in a custom service class? examples in symfony docs shows usage in a controller class... https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Comment: @anonymous007 I would use them in the Controller but instead of building an Entity I would build that DTO we talked about. And yes, an EventSubscriber can work as  you said. Sorry but I don't think the question should be extended, it's becoming another question altogether about how ParamConverters work and not about SRP nor SOLID.